# Sending &amp; in Server URL ASP.NET MVC IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

We're using ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor View engine and standard HTML and jquery on the client side. We're trying to pass an "&" in the post url of a search request but we are always getting an *A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)*, though we did encode it from the javascript side using encodeURIComponent

```
http://localhost:6200/en/us/home/GetPoints/cat-0,gov-0,city-0,key-casper%26gambibi,addr-!1!10
```

Thanks
Yehia

Comment: Move that information into the query string? Then you don't have to parse `cat-0,gov-0,city-0,key-casper%26gambibi,addr-!1!10` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to modify the requestPathInvalidCharacters attribute of the HttpRuntime node in the web.config

[httpRuntime Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

By using the following HttpRuntime configuration setting you can keep validation tight by removing the & character validation check however leaving the others in place.

The defaults for "requestPathInvalidCharacters" are "<,>,*,%,&,:,\".
So just remove the &.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="20"
requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?"  />
```

But as Chris mentions in his comment above, passing the search values in the query string will work without the above httpRuntime change:

```
http://localhost:6200/en/us/home/GetPoints?paramName=key-casper%26gambibi&......
```